# Why doesn't iterating over each index of a string not function correctly?

Tags: ruby, iteration

I'm trying to perform an operation on each character of a string which is followed by another character, i.e. one that is not the last character. My code is:

```
[0..(str.length - 2)].each do |index|
    // do something with index
end
```

The code errors out. `[0..(str.length - 2)]` returns a range object rather than an actual range which can be iterated over. Putting a `return index` in the body of the above causes a single iteration, with an output of something like `[0..7]`. Why isn't this iterating over each number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By enclosing the range in [..], you have created an Array containing a single Range object. In other words, the length of your Array is one. You just want:

```
(0..(str.length - 2)).each do |index|
    // do something with index
end
```

Answer (score 3):

What you've got there is an array containing a `Range` rather than a single range, so each is yielding you that one range rather than the integers in that range. Replace the [] with () and you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
(0..(str.length - 2)).each do |index|
    // do something with index
end
```